# orientation bug with -webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch

Tags: css, ios5, webkit, scroll, mobile-safari

I have been playing around with -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; for a while and I getting randomly the following problem:

**I only need scroll top/bottom ( width is fixed ), but sometimes the user needs to scroll left and right to
trigger the vertical scroll.**

In other words, the user has to scroll horizontally to make the container scroll vertically.

again it is random, some times it just works.

I already have check all the relative positions for the child elements within the scroll.

any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had as well a scroll that never broke and by looking at the html inside it I realised that if you apply the -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; in ul element it will never break.

the scroll that used to break had many elements within it and all I had to do was make the ul elements scrollable separately.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem, been struggling with it forever until I did this:

Changed `overflow-y: scroll` to `overflow: scroll`. I've loaded up the page close to 20 times now and haven't experienced the left/right going up/down weirdness.

Comment: I've tried this approach and didn't fix the problem in my case ...

how does the html you are using look like?

Comment: Well, it appears to have simply been a glitch. It is now doing the bug 100% of the time. I need to figure out if there was another change that I did... The search continues, I'm afraid.

Comment: Try checking this out as well: http://travisjbeck.com/blog/browsers/webkit-overflow-scroll-touch-vertical-scrolling-only-responds-to-horizontal-swiping/

Comment: interesting and good to know the body with hidden visibility issue... the solution above fixed my problem tho, am getting the proper scroll direction 100% of the time now... hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments by Graygilmore. This worked for me:

// NOTE 2019-04-09: [referenced link was removed]

Make sure no parent element of the scrollable area is visibility:hidden or display:none.

Comment: got some link rot

Answer (score 0):

I work on a complex web application that uses multiple iframes.  I have a window.setInterval setup that removes native scrolling from hidden iframes and adds it to the visible iframe.  This works great except I experienced the same issue where I had to swipe left / right to scroll up down.  I noticed if you opened or clicked on a different browser tab and then clicked back it fixed itself.  We fixed our issue by adding the following jQuery after we apply the native scrolling to the visible iframe:

```
$(window).height($(window).height());
```

I am thinking this must force a repaint similar to clicking on a different tab and then clicking back does.  Hopefully this helps someone in a similar situation!